# Getting facet count 0 in solr

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am using solr search with faceting in my application. My use case is in such a way that the index files in the datadir keeps on changing.

The problem is, when I facet based on a particular field. I get the value from the indices that where previously in the data dir (and are not present currently). However they are returned with a value of 0. I don't understand where the values from the previous indices are persisted and are returned during a totally newer search?

Though I can simply skip the facets with count 0, I understand that this can seriously eat over my scalability. Any pointers to not include the facets from previous searchers?

[Edit 1] : The current workaround I am using is add a `facet.mincount=1` in my URL. But still, I guess this can eat over my performance.

Comment: Are you sure your changes are committed? That might be why you are showing results from prior searcher(s). Anyway, using `facet.mincount=n` is not a workaround, it is the correct way to exclude facet counts of less than n.

Comment: ^ Indeed. When you send a <commit /> all searchers are restarted. Faceting is a bit performance eater, but using mincount won't affect the performance at all..

Comment: +1 for facet.mincount=1, helped in my case.

Comment: Why "guess" about performance when you can be sure ? ask another SO question ;)

Answer (score 3):

I couldnt find a comment option & I dont have enough reputation to vote-up! 
I have the same exact problem. 
We are using atomic updates with solr 4.2.

I found some explanation here: http://collab.sakaiproject.org/pipermail/oae-dev/2011-November/000693.html

Excerpt:

> To efficiently handle facets for multi-valued fields (like tags), Solr
>   builds an "uninverted index" (which you think would just be called an
>   "index", but I suppose that's even more confusing), which maps
>   internal document IDs to the list of terms they contain.  Calculating
>   facets from this data structure just requires walking over every
>   document in the result set, looking up the terms it contains in the
>   uninverted index, and adding them to the tally for all documents.
>
> However, there's a sneaky optimisation here that causes the zero
>   counts we're seeing.  For terms that appear in more than 5% of
>   documents, Solr doesn't include them in the uninverted index (leaving
>   them out helps to keep the size in memory down, I guess), and instead
>   gets the count for these terms using a regular query against the
>   Lucene index.  Since the set of "common" terms isn't specific to your
>   result set, and since any given result set won't necessarily contain
>   all of these terms, you can get back counts of zero.

It may not be from old index values but just terms that exist in more than 5% of documents?

Answer (score 2):

I think `facet.mincount=n` is not a workaround, you should use it to get only the non-negative facet count.

```
solrQuery.setQuery("*:*");
solrQuery.addFacetField("foobar");
solrQuery.setFacetMinCount(1);
```